# How to efficiently parallelize EXTRACT function in raster package R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, extract, raster

Given a netcdf file, I am trying to extract all pixels to form a `data.frame` for later export to `.csv`

```
a=brick(mew.nc)
#get coordinates 
coord<-xyFromCell(a,1:ncell(a))
```

I can extract data for all pixels using `extract(a,1:ncell(a))`. However, I run into memory issues.

Upon reading through various help pages, I found that one can speed up things with:

```
beginCluster(n=30)
b=extract(a, coord)
endCluster()
```

But I still run out of memory. Our supercomputer has more than `1000 nodes, each node has 32 cores.`

**My actual rasterbrick has 400,000 layers**

I am not sure how to parrallize this task without running into memory issues.

Thank you for all your suggestions.

[Sample data of ~8MB can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o441544dzsigtm/mew.nc?dl=0)

Comment: If you are running into memory issues without parallelization, I'm not sure running the code in _several_ cores will alleviate the problem. Probably exactly the opposite. The solution will probably depend on what your end goal with 400k layers is.

Comment: @Roman, you're right!  However, is there a way to extract data for one layer at a time then cbind the output? A friend needs the data for further processing outside of `R` and `MATLAB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines to avoid memory problems

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 

outfile <- 'out.csv'
if (file.exists(outfile)) file.remove(outfile)

tr <- blockSize(b)
b <- readStart(b)
for (i in 1:tr$n) {
    v <- getValues(b, row=tr$row[i], nrows=tr$nrows[i])
    write.table(v, outfile, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, col.names=!file.exists(outfile))
}
b <- readStop(b)
```

To parallelize, you could do this by layer, or groups of layers; and probably all values in one step for each subset of layers. Here for one layer at a time:

```
f <- function(d) {
   filename <- extension(paste(names(d), collapse='-'), '.csv')
   x <- values(d)
   x <- matrix(x) # these two lines only needed when using
   colnames(x) <- names(d)  # a single layer
   write.csv(x, filename, row.names=FALSE)
}

# parallelize this:
for (i in 1:nlayers(b)) {
    f(b[[i]])
}
```

or

```
x <- sapply(1:nlayers(b), function(i) f(b[[i]]))
```

You should *not* be using `extract`. The question I have is what you would want such a large csv file for.

Comment: Thank you for making my work easier. The first part is probably more suitable given that it produces a `dataframe` while the parallel part produces many file as number of layers. This will require that I import the `.csv` files and produce a `dataframe`.